# Finding the highest n values for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I happened to the same problem as this [Finding the highest n values of each group in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541963/finding-the-highest-n-values-of-each-group-in-mysql)

I have some data like this:

```
+ --------- + ----------- +
| lane      | series      |
+ --------- + ----------- +
| 1         | 680         |
| 1         | 685         |
| 1         | 688         |
| 2         | 666         |
| 2         | 425         |
| 2         | 775         |
+ --------- + ----------- +
```

And I'd like to grab the highest n series per lane (let's say 2 for the sake of this example, but it could be many more than that)
So the output should be:

```
+ --------- + ----------- +
| lane      | series      |
+ --------- + ----------- +
| 1         | 688         |
| 1         | 685         |
| 2         | 775         |
| 2         | 666         |
+ --------- + ----------- +
```

I think the SQL with "funky" MySQL features are quite good.

```
set @count:=-1, @lane:=0; 
select lane, series
from (select lane, series from lane_series order by lane, series desc) x
where if(lane != @lane, @count:=-1, 0) is not null
and if(lane != @lane, @lane:=lane, lane) is not null
and (@count:=@count+1) < 2; -- Specify the number of row at top of each group here
```

To my surprise, it works very well on MySQL 5.0 and MySQL 5.1, but it doesn't work on MySQL 5.5 which is my production MySQL version.

The result on MySQL 5.5 is like this:

```
+ --------- + ----------- +
| lane      | series      |
+ --------- + ----------- +
| 1         | 688         |
| 1         | 685         |
+ --------- + ----------- +
```

Please help me to make it work on MySQL 5.5 or tell me why the result is different, thanks a lot!

UPDATE:
Because there're about 3 million records in my production database,  I'd like to know how to get the result in a fast way,  as fast as possible.

Comment: Try some other way for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+mysql

Answer (score 5):

Try this one, maybe it will work for you.

```
SELECT lane, series
FROM   tableA
WHERE (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM   tableA AS f
        WHERE  f.lane = tableA.lane AND 
               f.series >= tableA.series
      ) <= 2
ORDER BY lane, series DESC
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/826d8/5)

Comment: You did a great work here, and also in 'Broken Arrow' and 'Face off'

Comment: @DhruvPathak off topic, those were movies haha

Comment: but John Woo was the director !

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot.
I tried this SQL in my db which has about 30 million records. 
It costs a lot of time to return records. 

I think the Time Complexity is O(n^2).   
Do you have ways to return result in one pass.